# Inner DIVs to fill height of Parent Div

Tags: css, html, css-float, height

Sorry. I had to edit my question:  I made the second image in Photoshop.

**I am trying to find a DIV equivalent to a Table. How do you get divs to behave like TDs: All TDs adjust their height as the content grows, and all TDS have the same height to the bottom of the Table element. **  Why is this so hard with DIVs? After all these years, is'nt there a standard solution?

[image]

1. How do you get the two column divs to always be the same height (or always go down to the bottom) of the container DIV?
2. As the innner content grows, the wrapper DIV (in red) will grow with it, and maintain its padding (just like a table would).

Comment: Please post the CSS your using.

Comment: Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to the container

Comment: ^^ I almost suggested that, but I've answered two questions that way already today (and was correct).

Comment: I think it's the answer considering he included the `css-float` tag - that's usually the culprit as a containers height *should* grow with it's content by default.

Answer (score 6):

yeah, your concept appears really tough to accomplish in CSS alone, for some reason. JQuery could handle it a lot better if you're open to it.

At any rate, here is is another alternative. It uses a [clever trick](http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/s8uLG/3/) as follows:

```
#container div { float: left; background: #ccc; width: 200px; margin-bottom: -2000px; padding-bottom: 2000px; }
```

Check it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jplew/yPMVJ/

[image: mockup]

Comment: Thanks for that effort, JP! When I added padding, paragraph cells would collapse.  I tried, but the left column only lights up over the paragraph. I couldn't get it to work with the col1 div.
Here's what I got: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanjohnsond/L7ukr/
Do you have a JQuery solution?

Comment: I am looking at the css newbie page. If you know a better solution, I am game to see it  CSS Newbie:  http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/equal-heights/plugin.html

Comment: yeah, this is kind of a "hackish" technique which relies on manipulating margin-bottom and padding-bottom values. In your example, you set `padding: 20px`, which will break the layout  because it's over-riding the `padding-bottom: 2000px` we set at the onset. So this method has its limitations. I don't have a jQuery solution off-hand. It wouldn't be that hard to build though, you would calculate like this: height of the last row = ( window height - sum of the height of all the previous divs in the column)

Comment: I am going to try to use JavaScript and traverse the DOM and force it.

Comment: Instead of an arbitrary massive number for negative bottom margin and bottom padding, why not use 100%? I tried in your fiddle, and it seems to work, and would work on heights over 2000px.

Comment: @SeanKendle ok great, all the better. glad you were able to get some use out of it.

Comment: Well, I couldn't actually use that, because my divs have drop shadows which are cut off at the bottom.  I will keep it in mind for the future.  I swallowed my pride and used "display: table-cell" instead.  O_o  

I am ashamed of myself.

Comment: I'm amazed it's 2014 and we're still stuck with fundamental problems in CSS like this. ARrrg

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
  <div name="outer">
   <div name="inner>put your contents here</div>
   <div style="clear: both"></div> 
  </div>
```

you need a div that has the "clear:both" style (clear both simple makes the div takes up a entire line, nothing can float around it) at the very end of your inner divs so the outer div knows to extend to the end.

Comment: This forces the *outer* container to grow to the size of the *inner* containers, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you have `float`s in the children divs. In that case you can do either of the followings:

1. Add `overflow:auto;` to the parent div's style.
2. Use [CSS Clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)
3. Add another tag (last tag under the parent div) containing `clear:both` style like the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I mocked up a solution on JSfiddle using simple percentages:
http://jsfiddle.net/xLSQX/

[image: mockup]

Otherwise, as mentioned above pay attention to the `overflow:` attribute and `clear: both`.

I want all the divs inside the container to act like table cells and the outer div to act like the  element.  The height of the outer div to be flexible and adjust to the height of all the content inside the other divs.
[image]

Comment: JP Lew, is there anyway to turn off the scroll bar? I want the height of the outer div to be flexible and adjust to the height of all the content inside the other divs

Comment: @user2374200 Do not edit someone's answer to show him/her a picture. Instead, put the link in your comment, like so: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SQHhm.png

Comment: Jerry how did you make that linK?

Comment: Look at this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SQHhm.png
As the innner content grows, the wrapper DIV (in red) will grow with it, and maintain its padding (just like a table would). DIVs acting just like table cells:

Comment: @user2374200 After uploading the picture, you just paste the link in the comment box :)

Comment: I tried a Faux Columns, but it's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanjohnsond/v5sBg/1/